# Is there any way for Intellij to bold or highlight directory that has file changes like Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way in Packages or Projects pane to highlight or bold directories/path that has local file changes (diff from VCS repository).  Eclipse has this.

I know there is a way to get all the changes if I change the pane to Changed files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Settings -> Version Control -> Show directories with changed descendants.

Comment: And for those just starting with intellij, this would be under the File menu -> Settings (Ctrl-Alt-S)

Answer (score 6):

On new version of IDE, this settings were moved to:
**Settings -> Version Control -> Confirmation** and enable "Highlight directories that contain modified files in the Project tree"

Comment: This is now the correct answer (IntelliJ 2023)